# Php libraries error in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Im having this problem with php in my ubuntu 16 machine.

[image]
I have already install them independently with for example:

```
sudo aptitude install php7.0-gettext
```

but still getting those errors.

Comment: Fix your php.ini, do `ll /usr/lib/php/20151012` you will see no. dll files.. linux uses .so files not dll's

Comment: should i change the libraries extensions ?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ?

Comment: No fix the `php.ini` did you just copy it over from windows or something? You would not get these errors if you did just `sudo apt-get -y install php7.0 php7.0-{mbstring,curl,gd,mcrypt,json,xml,mysql,sqlite,gettext,cli}`

Comment: Handling dependencies for interpreted apps does _not_ get more fun with experience.  I highly recommend considering using docker to express your codes requirements.

Answer (score 0):

as we know, php can run windos os and unix-like os, so in php, there are two kind of extension： *.dll and *.so,  in config file(php.ini), we also can see it.

- *.dll is the extension used on windows
- *.so is the exntesion used on unix-like os

on the ubuntu , you should use *.so extension,  not *.dll extension. and you check the dir `/usr/lib/php/20151012`, you can kwon that.

Comment: yes but still php is looking for dlls. how can i set php to run as ubuntu.

Comment: you should locate your php.ini, php -i|grep ini,  search extension config in php.ini